# systemd-boot timeout value in loader.conf is ignored

Tags: boot, bootloader

I am Dual Booting Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10, Recently I came to know about systemd-boot and tried it.

This is my file content `/boot/efi/loader/loader.conf`

```
timeout 60
auto-entries 0
auto-firmware 0
default 1
editor yes
```

while trying to understand the options while booting, I pressed t, Shift t, +, - buttons and then some how the value is set at 10 and the system countdown always shows 10. But my value in `loader.conf` for timeout is 60, I prefer the value set in `loader.conf`

Question: how can I configure systemd boot to use the value in `loader.conf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several trails, I found it.

need to press "-" or "Shift t" until the time out reaches 0 and then two more key presses will show you the value entered in `loader.conf` file. this means hereon-wards the time out value in `loader.conf` file will be used.

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Also pressing 'h' key will display a breve help that is very useful

Comment: Solved my issue, my timeout was set at 1780 seconds for some strange reason, Thanks!